# Managed Metadata changes not applied to list items after term change

Tags: managed-metadata

I have tried 2 scenarios to update the term store data (on a wiki page content type)

1. I update a term and hit up and the changes are not reflected on a content type (wiki page) where I am using that meta data item.  After making the term item update (changing text) and navigating back to the wiki page I inspect the properties and the value is not showing the updated value.
2. The other scenario...I have also tried to merge term store items.  In view mode the page property shows the old label value.  When I go into edit mode it shows the correct value which is good however this also would require me to navigate to every page go into edit mode and hit update/save on the page (in order to get the correct property value).

How can I get the label value of the meta data to update (when making changes to the term store).

I have found this article and ensured that the Taxonomy Update Scheduler is executing but the term values are not getting updated.
http://www.paulgrimley.com/2011/02/managed-metadata-changes-not-applied-to.html

NOT sure where to look now.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

thx

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I'm having the same problem on a site. Kind regards, Jurgen

Comment: David DId you had a solution for this?

Comment: We are having the same issue with SharePoint 2013 (March CU). I read somewhere about a hidden field that needs to be updated. http://prashobjp.wordpress.com/2013/09/30/updating-sharepoint-managed-metadata-term-hidden-value/ But I wasn't able to get this working in my environment.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me
https://sharepoint-relieved.blogspot.com/2014/09/taxonomy-update-scheduler-not-working.html

First run a full manual sync, then reset up the database triggers.

```
$url = Read-Host "Enter Url of site collection" 

$site=Get-SPSite $url
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession]::SyncHiddenList($site) 

$tax = Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site $url
$ts = $tax.TermStores[0]
$ts.UpdateUsedTermsOnSite($site)
$site.dispose()
```

Comment: This worked for me, Thank you. Article is very good though!